# List index out of range issue

Tags: python

Can somebody help me find the solution of this list index out of range issue? This is the code.

```py
list1 = {
    'I' : 1,
    'V' : 5,
    'X' : 10,
    'L' : 50,
    'C' : 100,
    'D' : 500,
    'M' : 1000
}

def func(x):
    arr = []
    i = 0
    res = 0
    j = i+1
   
    for z in x:
        arr.append(list1[z])

    while j < len(arr):
        if arr[i] >= arr[j]:
            res+= arr[i]

        elif arr[i] < arr[j]:
            res+= arr[i]*-1

        i+=1

print(func('VIII'))
```

I tried to use length function but it didn't help. I am still a beginner so I will be needing a lot of help...

Comment: For a list of length N where N > 0 then the valid subscripts for that list are in the inclusive range -N to N-1

Comment: Not clear the goal, what kind of data is  the function supposed to return? smt like `sum(map(list1.get, x))`?

Answer (score 1):

Your loop will run forever, because you never update the `j` variable in the loop. Here's the modififed code:

```
list1 = {

    'I' : 1,

    'V' : 5,

    'X' : 10,

    'L' : 50,

    'C' : 100,

    'D' : 500,

    'M' : 1000

}

def func(x):

    arr = []

    i = 0

    res = 0
    
    j = i+1

    for z in x:
        arr.append(list1[z])

    # if j can be in arr: pass
    # else make so that j can be in arr
    if j < len(arr):
        pass
    else:
        j = i

    while i < len(arr):
        if arr[i] >= arr[j]:

            res += arr[i]

        elif arr[i] < arr[j]:

            res+= arr[i]*-1

        i+=1

print(func('VIII'))
```

also note that `print(...)` in your code will print nothing since, you didn't returned any value from that function.

To return something in function use: `return ...`. This will also stop the function.

Comment: But when I input a single Roman number like print(func('V')). It throws an error

Comment: @KaushikDeveloper I edited my code it works now with single Roman numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you are trying to access an index that doesn't exist in the list. In your code, the error is caused by the while loop because you are incrementing j without checking if it has reached the end of the list. You should also increment i and update j inside the loop.
This should work:

```
list1 = {
    'I' : 1,
    'V' : 5,
    'X' : 10,
    'L' : 50,
    'C' : 100,
    'D' : 500,
    'M' : 1000
}

def func(x):
    arr = []
    res = 0
    for z in x:
        arr.append(list1[z])

    i = 0
    while i < len(arr) - 1:
        if arr[i] >= arr[i+1]:
            res += arr[i]
        else:
            res -= arr[i]
        i += 1

    # add the value of the last symbol
    res += arr[-1]
    return res

print(func('VIII'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while j < len(arr):
    if arr[i] >= arr[j]:
        res+= arr[i]
    elif arr[i] < arr[j]:
        res+= arr[i]*-1

    i+=1
```

`func` uses `j` in the loops predicate but increments `i`. Was that intention? So, `j` is always less than `len(arr)` while `i` will exceed the list's size.